# vscode 'Restart' debugger calls preLaunchTask, I would like it not to

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have configured a `preLaunchTask` in my project, so I'm sure my code is built, before debugging it. Works well, but:

In this use-case, it is annoying, that when I want to restart the debugging, and press the 'restart' button, the `preLaunchTask` is executed. This is the build process, which is lengthy, and in some setups fail, because the debugger, or other tools, have the file-under-debugging opened, so the build process can not write the file, and fails with access-denied. And it all goes bad from there ...

I understand that one could also use the `preLaunchTask` for other stuff, where one *wants* to call the `preLaunchTask`. Anyway, its current behavior now, and one should not break stuff for others.

So I'm proposing a property `runPreLaunchTaskOnDebuggerRestart`, that should be `true` per default (compatability), and can be set to `false` in my launch.json.

Are there any other options?

Should I file an 'issue' on GitHub?

(I'm writing this question/discussion here, as per 'contributing guidelines'!. Yes - I actually read (some of) the docs :-) )

Thx
/T